# android binary sms with port send/receive

Tags: android, sms

I am looking for a complete software library with an API with the following requirements:

1. supported platform: (would like) android 2.2.x and higher; i.e. if
   there is a solution for android honeycomb and higher only, that could be
   ok
2. send and receive GSM **multipart binary sms** to/from the handset
3. can get/set **sms port numbers** of the sms User Data Header
4. open source or commercial, no problem

specs 2 and 3 are necessary.

to understand better the problem:

I am porting a j2me application which requires JSR 120 to the android platform; 
the ported android application must communicate with existing j2me applications, which use multipart binary sms with port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I posted a question here about two months ago and received no answers:

[How to send multipart binary sms in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057776/how-to-send-multipart-binary-sms-in-android/12179028#12179028)

In my case, the clients always send the messages to a server. So the solution was to encode the message in BASE64 and send as multipart TEXT sms. At the server side, I checked if the sms was on a specific port to decide if I treat it as binary or as BASE64 before re-sendig.

I don't know if it can be applied to your case, since you would have to modify the existing j2me applications (if clients communicate directly).

If you find a better solution, I would like to know.